# installing phonegap plugin from github error "project directory could not be found"

Tags: plugins, cordova, websocket

I get the error "project directory could not be found" when I try to run this command:

phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket

I'm following the instructions here 
https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket

I can't figure out what this means...  Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be in the project folder before you launch the phonegap plugin command.

Usually you get this error when you launch the command from outside the project.